# Remove string value from a numeric column Pandas?

Tags: python, database, pandas, dataframe

I'm look to remove the String value from my "average rating" column, can some one help?
[image]

[image]

Comment: What do you want to replace the string value with? 0? `np.nan`?

Comment: I want to delete the row or replace with 0

Comment: can you share us a example about your file here ? https://www.transferbigfiles.com/

Comment: @GiovaniSalazar what do I put for the email part?

Comment: the email is not important...just put anything mail...later you copy the link here

Comment: What have you tried? You say that you just want to delete the row, that’s a basic task. Your question is unclear though, so I’m not sure. Also, please include your code and data as text in the post itself, not as images.

Comment: try `pd.to_numeric(df['average_rating'],errors='coerce')` then you can use `df.dropna(subset='average_rating')` to get rid of those rows

Comment: @GiovaniSalazar database file: http://tbf.me/a/CVCdnX

Answer (score 3):

Here another example

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import ExcelWriter
from pandas import ExcelFile

df = pd.read_excel('goodreadsdata.xlsx')

df[['average_rating']] = df[['average_rating']].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')
# ALl Df
print(df)
# Average column average_rating without Nan Value
print (df['average_rating'].mean())
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the following simplified version of your table,

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd, numpy as np

input = """ 
 bookID,title,average_rating
 1,Foo,1.5 
 2,Bar,2.5 
 3,Baz,"Unwanted string" 
 4,Boo,3.5 
 5,Goo,"Another string" 
 """
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(input))
```

You can use the following to remove the rows of all non-numeric string values in your average_rating column.

```
df[np.isfinite(pd.to_numeric(df.average_rating, errors="coerce"))]
```